# Skipping values in a sequence of positive integers

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I want to print the following number sequence:

1 2 3 6 7 8 11 12 13 16 17 18...

It prints three positive integers then skips two following values and then repeats the process.

Comment: you can use modulo `%` operator to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way just using a `for` loop statement:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += ((i%5) == 3) ? 3 : 1)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That's C#, not C++

Comment: @SimonKraemer I removed the C# bit. :)

Comment: @CherubimAnand I know but as OP is obviously a beginner the examples should not be for other languages. This will only cause more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Franck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6667256/franck) you can simply use the modulo operator.

The modulo operator gives you the rest of a division as a result.

```
 0 / 10 =  0;  0 % 10 = 0;
10 / 10 =  1; 10 % 10 = 0;
11 / 10 =  1; 11 % 10 = 1;
12 / 10 =  1; 12 % 10 = 2;
20 / 10 =  2; 20 % 10 = 0;
21 / 10 =  2; 21 % 10 = 1;
27 / 10 =  2; 21 % 10 = 7;

0 % 3 = 0;
1 % 3 = 1;
2 % 3 = 2;
3 % 3 = 0;
4 % 3 = 1;
5 % 3 = 2;
6 % 3 = 0;
7 % 3 = 1;
8 % 3 = 2;
9 % 3 = 0;
...
```

From your example I assume that you want to skip values ending on `4` or `9`.
You have 2 possibilities to archive this:

- use `% 10` and check the result for being either `4` or `9`
- use `% 5` and check the result for being either `4`

The result would look something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=100; i++)
{
    if(i%5 == 4) continue; //Skip
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```